# android social-auth query

Tags: android, socialauth

I want to implement social authentication in android. I have gone through [android-social-auth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) . I found that it dose not support 2.2 froyo. Please suggest me library which support android 2.2 froyo.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well i have not used [getsocialize](http://www.getsocialize.com) yet but have read this [Documentation](http://socialize.github.com/socialize-sdk-android/). hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

actually now socialauoth support android 2.2 and less 
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/issues/detail?id=252

Comment: please download socialauth-android 2.0 jar